# Symfony2 Form FormType Itself collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a symfony 2 form 'PersonType', which has a `PersonType` collection field that should map a given person's children.

And I'm getting this error,

```
{"message":"unable to save order","code":400,"errors":["This form should not contain extra fields."]}
```

Here is my `Person` entity,

```
class Person
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orderitem_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

}
```

And my Type,

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('children', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new PersonType()
            ))
        ;
    }
```

UPDATE :
 I've seen that the problem was because the option :

```
'allow_add' => true,
'by_reference' => false
```

wasn't in the Type, I've deleted it because when i insert them, the form don't appear and the page crash with no error.

I'm very confused because with this error, people can't have children :/

Does anyone already faced the same problem? (A formType nested over itself)

ACUTALLY :
I've duplicate my personType to PersonchildrenType to insert this last in the first...

Comment: ( Thanks for edit, i'm very poor in english ^^ )

Comment: I would embed another form for starters, not the same one in itself. And see if that works.

Comment: One to other : it works perfectly, i've read the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html but, nothing about this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem except that the error message was :

> FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum function nesting level of 'MAX' reached, aborting!

Which is normal because "PersonType" is trying to build a form with a new "PersonType" field that is also trying to build a form with a new "PersonType" field and so on...

So the only way I managed to solve this problem, for the moment, is to proceed in two different steps :

1. Create the parent
2. Create a child and "link" it to the parent

You can simply do this in your controller

```
public function addAction(Person $parent=null){
    $person = new Person();
    $person->setParent($parent);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $person);
    if($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // some code here
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('path_to_person_add', array(
                'id'    => $person->getId()
            ); //this redirect allows you to directly add a child to the new created person
        }
    }
    //some code here
    return $this->render('YourBundle::yourform.html.twig', array(
        'form'    => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

I hope this can help you to solve your problem.
Tell me if you don't understand something or if I'm completly wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your form as a service, like described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services, and modify your form like this:

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person_form';
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('children', 'collection', array(
                'type' => 'person_form',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```